# Reading SIM contacts on Symbian S60

Tags: c++, mobile, symbian, s60

I am looking for a working code snippet for Symbian S60 5th edition in which you can read SIM contact details.

If possible, I would skip using `RPhoneBookSession`, but if that is the only way, please provide code snippet how to use it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the example code from the relevant chapter of the [Quick recipes on Symbian OS](http://www.quickrecipesonsymbianos.com) book, which you can find [here](http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/File:Quick_Recipes_on_Symbian_OS_Contacts_and_Agenda_Example_Code.zip).

EDIT-1:

Should have read the question more carefully.
The `CContactDatabase` API should synchronize with the SIM Phonebook seamlessly by using `RPhoneBookSession` so you don't have to.
To figure out what's wrong, I would suggest calling `RPhoneBookSession::GetLastSyncError`, `RPhoneBookSession::GetPhoneBookCacheState` and `RPhoneBookSession::GetSyncMode`.
I would also suggest doing all this both before and after adding a new `CContactICCEntry` to the database yourself.

Of course, this is all supposing Nokia didn't just brutally disable Phonebook synchronization...

EDIT-2:

If Nokia disabled Symbian's phonebook synchronization, they may have replaced it with their own, which would mean that using the `CPbkContactEngine::AllContactsView` method could yield different results than the `CContactDatabase` approach.

Let's face it, though. If the Contacts application provided with the phone doesn't even allow you to save a contact on the SIM, Nokia may have removed all possibilities to interact with the SIM phonebook period.

EDIT-3:

You could try to develop against phbksyncsvr.lib using the binaries in the [Product Development Kit (PDK)](http://developer.symbian.org/main/make_phone/index.php) from the first real version of the Symbian Foundation operating system: Symbian^2. Binary compatibilty between versions of Symbian OS can sometimes help you.

Comment: If you are referring to ContactReadField example and chapter 4.2.3.2, there are no KUidContactICCEntry in the database. I am looking for an example in which I read contacts from the SIM card.

Comment: According to the official documentation, RPhoneBookSession and phbksyncsvr.lib are not part of the S60 5th Edition SDK. How do I get that? Is there a way to get BAK these days?

Comment: I am not familiar with ADK. Are you referring to ADT - Application Development Toolkit? If so, can you point me to the directory where the library is placed?
As of the Application Development SDK for the first Symbian Foundation platform - Symbian^1 - this is a copy of the S60 5th Edition SDK v1.0 which does not contain the library and the headers.

Comment: I am getting this error on the PDK download page: 

"Export Control Error
The Symbian Foundation website is headlong into a limited beta phase now, and over the next few weeks we'll be stress testing our geo-targeting systems. While we do this, some of you, whole countries at a time, might have trouble accessing parts of the site. In fact, if you're seeing this message, it's happening right now."

Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Works fine from the UK. Very unfortunate. Might be worth trying every day and asking the foundation to have a wiki page to clarify what they can currently export where...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible without a private Nokia API.